# Getting Class Cast Exception when extends to Fragment in android..?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on an app where i am extending MainActivity to Fragment.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Fragment implements LocationListener{...}
```

When I executing the code in android 4.0 & later it's working good. When i am executing in android 2.3 it's getting class cast exception.

Error in LogCat

```
   E/AndroidRuntime(11123): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.fragment/com.test.fragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.fragment.MainActivity

   E/AndroidRuntime(11123): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.fragment.MainAcvitiy
```

As the following errors getting while executing code in android 2.3 version devices but cmg to 4.0 & later it's working good.

Added v4 and v7 libraries which support for fragments and actionbar ,but still facing same issue.

Comment: Looks like you are casting fragment to Activity. That part is missing from your post

Comment: Don't you have to have the support library set up in your application for Fragments to work in Android 2.3 or lower?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on your package import statements

The correct package import statement about Fragment in v4 supporting library is:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

but not

```
import android.app.Fragment
```